# Plotting groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am kind of new to pandas and I am trying to plot a line where x = month and y = number of times someone has been to a specific place. 
This is my code, but I think there is something wrong in the plot and also I think that I made it more complicated than it is. 
Do you have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_s = pd.read_csv(file2, delimiter=',')
data_s['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_s['StartDate'])
data_s['YearMonth'] = data_s['Date'].map(lambda x: 1000*x.year + x.month)
Place = data_s[data_s['Place'] == 'USA'].groupby('YearMonth')['Place'].count()

result = pd.DataFrame({'X': data_s['Date'].map(lambda x: 1000*x.year + x.month), 'Y': AGP})
result.plot()
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with the plot? What is it doing vs what do you expect?

Comment: I would expect a line of months and counts and the x ax is counting 1,2,3,4,5, and then the date. The y has very high values (like 200000), where it should be like 10 times. The results from the groupby are ok, but the plot I dont know..